# How to find all included points (lats/lons) given vertices of different regions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

There are 16 regions in the Arctic, and I have been given the lat/lon vertices for each region. I need to find all of the points that exist inside each region. The data is 1.5x1.5 deg resolution, 0 to 358.5 longitudes, 90 to -90 latitudes.

I have attempted using matplotlib.path, and I've been able to handle where the longitudes cross from -180 to +180, however the central arctic (i.e., the north pole) seems to have trouble. It appears that drawing along ~80 deg north does not recognize that there are points leading all the way up to 90.

The code for the "problem region" (central arctic) is listed first, then the code for the other regions that do not cross over the -180/180 line follows.

```
# regions[i] represents a class of 16 regions
# Problem region!

x, y = np.meshgrid(lons, lats) 
x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()
points = np.vstack((x,y)).T

lons_temp = regions[i].lons - 180
lons_temp = np.append(lons_temp, lons_temp[0])
lats_temp = np.append(regions[i].lats, regions[i].lats[0])
cross = np.where(np.diff(np.signbit(lons_temp)))[0]
lons_temp = lons_temp + 180
for c in cross:
    cross_point = lons_temp[c]
    if cross_point<90:
        mid_val = 0
    elif cross_point >= 90 and cross_point < 270: 
        mid_val = 180
    elif cross_point >=270:
        mid_val = 360
    interp = np.interp(mid_val, lons_temp[c:c+2], lats_temp[c:c+2])
    lons_temp = np.insert(lons_temp, c+1, mid_val)
    lats_temp = np.insert(lats_temp, c+1, interp)

    lons_neg = lons_temp[np.where(lons_temp <= 180)]
    lats_neg = lats_temp[np.where(lons_temp <= 180)]
    lons_pos = lons_temp[np.where(lons_temp >= 180)]
    lats_pos = lats_temp[np.where(lons_temp >= 180)]

    gg_neg = np.array([lons_neg, lats_neg])
    gg_pos = np.array([lons_pos, lats_pos])
    pp_neg = gg_neg.T # lon lat pair
    pp_pos = gg_pos.T
    p_neg=Path(pp_neg, closed=False)
    p_pos=Path(pp_pos, closed=False)
    grid_neg = p_neg.contains_points(points)
    grid_pos = p_pos.contains_points(points)
    grid = np.logical_or(grid_neg, grid_pos)
    grid = np.where(points.T[1]>=82.5, True, grid)

latslons1 = np.where(grid==True)[0]
regions[i].included_points = latslons1
```

```
# Other regions that do not cross over -180/180
x, y = np.meshgrid(lons, lats) 
x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()
points = np.vstack((x,y)).T

gg = np.array([regions[i].lons, regions[i].lats])
pp = gg.T
p=Path(pp)
grid = p.contains_points(points)

latslons1 = np.where(grid==True)[0]
regions[i].included_points = latslons1
```

I expect there is a way to encompass all of the regions in one block of code where it can handle wrapping around the -180/180 line as well as fix the issue of the central arctic. The link below shows an image of what I am trying to reproduce (however, I truly need the data points to be correct for analysis). https://nsidc.org/data/masie/browse_regions

Answer (score 0):

This code alone doesn't work so I have tried to fill in the gaps by creating the input data.

Please see [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

By defining the offending region as below, the lower section of your code works. This suggests that the problem is dependent on the coordinates for the area including the pole are defined. If you modify these you should be able to make it compliant with .contains_points

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import path

# create missing data

lons = np.arange(0,360,1.5)
lats = np.arange(-90,90.1,1.5,)

class polyg:
    lons = []
    lats=[]

# unproblematic region
region = polyg()
region.lats = np.array([80.,85.,80.])
region.lons = np.array([100.,100.,110.])
regions=[region]


# Including North pole
region = polyg()
region.lats = np.array([80.,80.,90.,90.])
region.lons = np.array([0.,360.,360.,0.])
regions.append(region)

i=1

x, y = np.meshgrid(lons, lats) 
x, y = x.flatten(), y.flatten()
points = np.vstack((x,y)).T

gg = np.array([regions[i].lons, regions[i].lats])
pp = gg.T
p=path.Path(pp)
grid = p.contains_points(points)

latslons1 = np.where(grid==True)[0]
regions[i].included_points = latslons1


print(x[latslons1])

print(y[latslons1])

[  0.    1.5   3.  ... 355.5 357.  358.5]
[81. 81. 81. ... 90. 90. 90.]
```

Comment: Note: Please don't ignore the effort put into solving *your* problem and comment back, letting me know if this was useful and if not why. If this has solved your problem, then please Accept the answer.